# `"C:\xampp\mysql\bin"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: mysql, windows, access-control, command-line

I am trying to access to `mysql` from windows command prompt by this command:

```
"C:\xampp\mysql\bin" mysql -u root - p
```

But it sayas:

> `"C:\xampp\mysql\bin"' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

But when I do these, it works:

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root - p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the following instead:

```cmd
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p
```

<sub>*assuming you are using a CMD / DOS Prompt*</sub>

Depending on the path in which your mysql.exe resides, you might have to incorporate using double quotes as follows:

```cmd
""C:\Program Files (x86)\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p"
```

<sub>*assuming you are using a CMD / DOS Prompt*</sub>

You add double-quotes from `"C:\...` to the end of the executable `...exe"` and then add double-quotes at the beginning of the whole command until the end. You end up with the above command.

***Reference:*** [Long Filenames or Paths with Spaces Require Quotation Marks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/102739/long-filenames-or-paths-with-spaces-require-quotation-marks) (Microsoft Support)

Comment: No it doesn't work. It results a long list of options introduction.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You could try without the double-quotes.

Comment: But it works with a specific user like this `"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u m - p`   Why this happens?
`

Comment: The result is same although with double quotes!

Comment: The `-p` parameter should be without a space.

Comment: Oh yeah! the problem was about mistaken space between `- p`. Thank you!